# Python load text and move lines

Tags: python, templates, jinja2, txt

I have the following output from jinja template.
My target is to get a yaml file
Input file is

```
source_token = ACL_1_source

ips_netmask = {'mask': 0, 'ip': '0.0.0.0'}

ips_netmask = ##{'mask': 0, 'ip': '0.0.0.0'}


source_token = acl_2_source

ips_netmask = {'mask': 0, 'ip': '0.0.0.0'}

ips_netmask = ##{'mask': 0, 'ip': '0.0.0.0'}
```

output file that i want is

```
ips_netmask =   {'mask': 0, 'ip': '0.0.0.0'}
                {'mask': 0, 'ip': '0.0.0.0'}
                {'mask': 0, 'ip': '0.0.0.0'}


source_token = acl_2_source


ips_netmask =   {'mask': 0, 'ip': '0.0.0.0'}
                {'mask': 0, 'ip': '0.0.0.0'}
                {'mask': 0, 'ip': '0.0.0.0'}
```

Try with cycle from itertool but not easy to maintain. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you want to transform the first output to the second one using Python only, then Jinja is unrelated to the problem. If you want to modify the jinja template, so instead the first output it will produce the second one, then you need to add your **jinja template** into the question post. In both cases you need to add more description about "rules", according to which the desired output should be produced.